# Exporting and encrypting a DE without admin access

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm in the process of designing a framework in Marketing Cloud where the requirement is to export and encrypt a specified Data Extension without admin access to the account.

The user currently has admin access which will be revoked at a later time. There's no problem with the user exporting but we require the data extension exports to be encrypted. I'm wondering if this is possible in Marketing Cloud?

Any help is appreciated.